# Reusing variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I want to know if reusing the same set of variables can lead to any unforeseen events in a bash script .Is it generally regarded as a good practice ?

To make my query a bit more clearer.

I have a script which goes like this :

```
max=`cat loc1.c  | wc -l`   
bar=1        

while [ $bar -lt $max ]
do

    f1=`awk -v vr1=$bar 'NR == vr1' loc1.c`
    f2=`awk -v vr1=$bar 'NR == vr1' loc2.c`

    if [[ a random file  exists ]] ; then # use var1 var2 var3 ; fi 
    if [[ a random file2 exists ]] ; then # use var1 var2 var3 ; fi 
    if [[ a random file3 exists ]] ; then # use var1 var2 var3 ; fi 

    ((bar++))
done
```

The files  loc1 and loc2 lists file paths separated by newlines . The paths are transferred with respect to the line numbers to the variables f1 and f2 . The loop continues until each file (pointed by the path) in loc1 has done some kind of data manupulation with files pointed in loc2.

Any kind of suggestions are welcome .

I am reusing the variables var1,var2 ,var3 [..] in the code that follows.

Comment: UUOC.  If you want `wc -l` to print only the number of lines (and not the filename), do not use cat.  Use redirection instead: `< loc1.c wc -l` or `wc -l < loc1.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue with reused variables is whether they are initialized appropriately at each point in the script where they are used.  If each paragraph always sets the value before using it, there's no harm in the reuse.  The main guideline should be clarity of the code.  If the code is clear, then there's no problem.

Once upon a long time ago, one might have argued that variable reuse saved memory; these days, I wouldn't bother with the claim.

Comment: @Geekasaur: Additional comments: Meaningful variable names are very important. They make code much easier to read and maintain. While "var1" is probably just a placeholder for the purposes of the question, I've seen far too much code (and written a little myself) with meaningless variable names. On the other hand, don't go out of your way to avoid reusing names. I've seen code with so many names that are minor variations of each other that it's impossible to keep straight how they do or don't relate.

Comment: Another point about initialization is scope. In Bash, using functions and the `local` declaration can help allow name reuse while reducing name collision risks. Speaking of name collision, make it a habit to use lowercase or mixed case variable names in shell scripts to avoid potential collision with shell or environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

Not related to variable use, but you can simplify your file iteration, assuming you don't need `bar` or `max` for anything else:

```
while read -r f1 && read -r -u 3 f2; do
    if [[ a random file  exists ]] ; then # use var1 var2 var3 ; fi 
    if [[ a random file2 exists ]] ; then # use var1 var2 var3 ; fi 
    if [[ a random file3 exists ]] ; then # use var1 var2 var3 ; fi
done < loc1.c 3< loc2.c
```